# Usando uma função math no vue 2 framework

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

Estou desenvolvendo uma api no vue.js que tem um botão para calcular a potencia de um determinado numero. Porém quando clico no botão fica estático, nada muda. Tem que fazer alguma mudança no método ou alguma configuração no vue?

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <p>{{ numero }}</p>
    <button @click="potencia">Potência 2*</button>
</div>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data: {
            numero: 3
        },
        methods: {
            potencia() {
                return Math.pow(this.numero, 2)
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Sua função retorna o resultado de `Math.pow`. Para onde vai esse valor? O que você gostaria de fazer com o resultado?

Comment: O botao deveria atualizar o valor de {{numero }} dentro da tag <p>.
Ex: se {{numero}} é 3, aperta o botao e {{numero}} fica 9. Entendeu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua função está retornando o resultado. O JavaScript tratará isso internamente e não saberá que o que deseja é atualizar o valor de `this.numero`. Para tal, você precisa especificar que deseja alterar o valor fazendo a atribuição:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    numero: 3
  },
  methods: {
    potencia() {
      this.numero = Math.pow(this.numero, 2)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ numero }}</p>
  <button @click="potencia">Potência 2*</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Nossa que deslize meu. Muito obrigado!!